# Variable width of bootstrap model

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I have a bootstrap model, which contains a 3 column layout. Each column contains a table with several `tbody` elements. The last column may contain hidden table elements (generated with `style: 'display:none'`).

If all elements of the last column are hide, I want the modal to resize to fit to the smaller content. Currently the width stays the same, whatever content is displayed. How can I get such a behaviour?

Comment: Please provide an online demo to demonstrate the issue in action. Also posting the relevant code would be great.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to actually give those columns a class and set their width to 0 or 1 px...

```
.one-wide { width:1px; }

<th class="one-wide">
```

But that is how i would solve it, since i like classes better anyway, you can just give them the display none as well.